# Performance issue with Groovy lists / maps

Tags: groovy

I have this code which compares two lists and find differences, so far so good, it works fine for small lists. Now Im testing with huge lists.
which contains **both** more than **300000** maps. It takes more than **5 hours** to process it. is that normal? How can I reduce the procssing time?

```
def list1 = [
    [cuInfo:"T12",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:22",appId:"G12355"],
    [cuInfo:"T13",service:"3",startDate:"12-02-16 13:00",appId:"G12356"],
    [cuInfo:"T14",service:"9",startDate:"10-01-16 11:20",appId:"G12300"], 
    [cuInfo:"T15",service:"10",startDate:"26-02-16 10:20",appId:"G12999"]
]
​
def list2 = [
    [name:"testname1",cuInfo:"T12",service:"3",startDate:"14-02-16 10:00",appId:"G12351"],
    [name:"testname1",cuInfo:"T13",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:00",appId:"G12352"],
    [name:"testname1",cuInfo:"T16",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:00",appId:"G12353"],
    [name:"testname2",cuInfo:"T14",service:"9",startDate:"10-01-16 11:20",appId:"G12301"], 
    [name:"testname3",cuInfo:"T15",service:"10",startDate:"26-02-16 10:20",appId:"G12999"],
    [name:"testname3",cuInfo:"T18",service:"10",startDate:"26-02-16 10:20",appId:"G12999"]  
]

def m1 = [:]
def m2 = [:]
def rows = list1.collect { me -> 
    [me, list2.find { it.cuInfo == me.cuInfo && it.service == me.service }] 
}.findAll {
            it[1]
}.findAll { 
    /*
     * This is where the differences are identified.
     * The 'name' attribute is excluded from the comparison,
     * by including only the desired attributes.
     */
    it[0] != it[1].subMap(['cuInfo', 'service', 'startDate', 'appId'])
}.collect {
    /*
     * At this point the list only contains the row pairs
     * which are different. This step identifies which columns
     * are different using asterisks.
     */
    (m1, m2) = it
    m1.keySet().each { key ->
        if(m1[key] != m2[key]) {
            m1[key] = "*${m1[key]}*"
            m2[key] = "*${m2[key]}*"
        }          
}

                [m1, m2]
            }.collect {
    [it[0].values(), it[1].values()].flatten() as String[]
}
```

Comment: Do some profiling to get actual performance bottleneck data, but you should consider using read data objects rather than maps and probably some @CompileStatic or actual Java code. Also, most Groovy constructs have a performance cost greater than what it would seem - Groovy does a lot under the covers.

Comment: Also, check your memory settings `-Xmx3G`? The first `collect` with your big lists will be doing at worst 90B iterations to return 300K new lists...  Run it whilst watching the memory usage under jvisualvm or jmc to see if you're topping out ram and forcing a lot of GC

Comment: @tim_yates I know the bottle neck is the first collect() I tried the code on two different machines, it gives the same result

Comment: Two machines with the same ram and default jvm settings? Then the results will be the same if memory is the issue

Comment: @tim_yates, The machines are different, one is linux and the other is windows, and the jvms are also different. But anyway, for data processing like find differences, I will try stored procedure and use Groovy for the rest.

Comment: @sade can't you build a map of the larger one of the two lists, where you use the cuInfo and service as keys so the lookup can be done in constant time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help a little. I didn't have time to test but your code has a lot of collects and find alls that can cause performance issues

```
def results = []
list1.each{ lst1 ->

    def list1WithDifferences = []
    def list2WithDifferences = []
    def add = false

    def match = list2.find{ lst2 -> lst2.cuInfo == lst1.cuInfo && lst2.service == lst1.service }    

    match.each{k, v -> 
        if(k != 'name'){
            if(v != lst1[k]){
                add = true
                list1WithDifferences << "*${lst1[k]}*"
                list2WithDifferences << "*${v}*"
            }else{
                list1WithDifferences << v
                list2WithDifferences << v
            }
        }else{
            list2WithDifferences << v
        }
    }

    if(add){
        results << list1WithDifferences + list2WithDifferences
    }
}
println(results)
```

Comment: Thanks, it help a bit , but the processing is still long

Comment: I think you might have other issues then. I tested this in Groovy console with 300,000 maps and it took 6000 milliseconds while the original one couldn't even finish and froze my console.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but for those reading this I think it will be useful to understand how to improve runtime.
The code above runs in *O(mn)*, where *m, n* are the sizes of `list1` and `list2`. With *m=n=300_000* maps you have about *90_000_000_000* iterations as @tim_yates stated in the comments.

As a rule of thumb, avoid algorithms with more than *10_000_000* iterations unless you're an incredibly patient person.

For nested loops like

```
list1.collect { 
    ...
    list2.find {
        ...
```

this is usually *O(mn)*, because `find` has to iterate through the `list2`, resulting in *O(n)* each time it is called.
The way to avoid this is in @cfrick's comment. Create a map and reduce the one-time lookup time to approximately *O(1)*. Here's an example where the code isn't particularly pretty, but the code should be able to process lists of 1_000_000 maps each in a matter of seconds.

```
Closure mapCompareKey = { Map map -> map.subMap(['cuInfo', 'service']) }
Set keys = ['cuInfo', 'service', 'startDate', 'appId']
Closure mapsEqual = { Map x, Map y -> x.subMap(keys) == y.subMap(keys) }

Map map1 = list1.groupBy { mapCompareKey(it) }
        .collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v.first()]}

Map map2 = list2.groupBy { mapCompareKey(it) }
        .collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v.first()]}

List diffs = map2.findAll { compareKey, _ -> compareKey in map1 }
    .findAll { compareKey, map -> !mapsEqual(map, map1[compareKey]) }
    .collect { compareKey, map ->
        map1[compareKey].collect { k, v -> !(k in keys) ? v : (v == map."$k" ? v : "*$v*") } +
        map.collect { k, v -> !(k in keys) ? v : (v == map1[compareKey]."$k" ? v : "*$v*") }
    }
```